# CasperJS returning null elements in NodeList

Tags: javascript, document, casperjs, nodelist

Here is the script I am running:

```
//Require CasperJS
var casper = require('casper').create();

//Scraping Courserank
var base = "https://www.courserank.com";
var home = base + "/w/home";
var schools = base + "/w/schools?switchSchool=1";

//First, navigate to homepage and login
casper.start(home, function() {
    console.log('Logging in...');
    //Fill in the login form
    this.fill(
            'form[action="login"]', 
            { username : 'hatboysam@gmail.com', password : "****" },
            true
            );
});

function getSchools() {
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll('div.link');
    return arr;
}

//Go to the schools page
casper.then(function() {
    console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());
    //Open the school choice page
    casper.open(schools).then(function() {
        console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());
        //Get all school links
        var schools_arr = this.evaluate(getSchools);
        console.log(schools_arr.length);
        Array.prototype.map.call(schools_arr, function(elem) {
            console.log(elem.innerHTML);
        });
    });
});

casper.run();
```

Everything goes fine until the inner loop of the map call, specifically `console.log(elem.innerHTML)`.  Many of the elements in `schools_arr` are null.  If I add an `if(elem != null) { ... }` around the `console.log` statement it's all fine but that defeats the point.  When I run the same `document.querySelectorAll` in the Chrome console on the page none of the 513 elements in the NodeList are null.  CasperJS also reports 513 elements, but it shows many as null.  What's going on here?  Is the page not loading fully?  I have never used CasperJS before so sorry if this is a newbie mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't return native node elements from the page context using `evaluate()`; you have to `Array#map` to something deserializable with `JSON.parse`.

So your `getSchools()` function should be doing something like:

```
function getSchools() {
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll('div.link');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(arr, function(elem) {
        return elem.innerHTML;
    });
}
```

Though I don't know what you can do with the node innerHTML string content… So it's usually better to map elements to their exact properties you need:

```
function getSchools() {
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll('div.link a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(arr, function(elem) {
        return elem.getAttribute('href');
    });
}
```

**Edit:** as requested in the comments, to fetch inner text for all links:

```
function getSchools() {
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll('div.link a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(arr, function(elem) {
        return elem.textContent;
    });
}
```

Comment: That seems to make a lot of sense, but that exact getSchools method (the top one) seems to be returning `null` after the map... any ideas why it might make the whole array null?  Removing the map call gets me back to where I was, non null array with null elements...

Comment: Because there's no easy bridging between the page env and the casper/phantom one; keep in mind all you can retrieve from an evaluate() call is always what is serializable by `JSON.stringify` (HTMLElements, NodeList aren't)

Comment: So then if your answer won't work, what's the preferred way?  All I want is the text contents of all divs on the page with the class "link".  That really shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @NiKo runned into similar issue, I think it should be stated in casper's docs, since it's non-obvious until you said it.